# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'draw_grid'

Tags: python

I have a ex12.py file containing the simple code of>

```
def draw_grid():   
    print(" | | ")  
    print("-----")  
    print(" | | ")
```

In the Python Shell I write the code>

```
>>>import ex12 
>>>ex12.draw_grid()
```

And I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>  
    ex12.draw_grid()  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'draw_grid'
```

I am quite new to Python and I don't know what's wrong with that syntax. I don't get an error after the import command, so I expected the module's function to be accessible.

Comment: hmmm, it works fine for me... Did you save four file? Is import working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you do `import ex12` for the first time, there isn't a `draw_grid()` function in `ex12.py`. After you added in the function, if you do not restart your shell but just simply call `import ex12` again, the change will not be reflected -- the shell can't see the new or updated function.

Workarounds:

1. Restart the shell and run again.
2. Use `reload(ex12)` to pull in updates from modules. Should be sufficient for quick and simple cases. Might bite you if classes and inheritance are used.

Does this help you?

Comment: For python 3.xx `reload()` become `imp.reload()`.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that a reboot is needed for re-importing a module. Now I am 1 step further in my python's education progress.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the latest version of your file is in your working directory?

try:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
```